# Get attachment ID of a video

Tags: php, wordpress, attachment

I am working in Wordpress.

Video is in media library. I put the video in the post from media library.

I have this code in content.php to show length of video:

```
$video_meta = get_post_meta( $attachment_id , '_wp_attachment_metadata', true );
echo $video_meta['length_formatted'];
```

But i don't know how to get  `$attachment_id`. How can i show dinamically in the post the ID of video attachments?

I am using twentythirteen theme. Last versione of WP.

Comment: Simply echo $attachment_id;

Comment: echo $attachment_id; returns 0

Comment: try var_dump($video_meta); and find attachment_id there if it is present in meta_data or in your brauser inspect web page meta_data.

Comment: var_dump($video_meta); returns NULL

Comment: $video_meta = get_post_meta( $attachment_id , '_wp_attachment_metadata', true );     Is this statement on the same page?

Comment: Sorry, var_dump($video_meta); returns bool(false)

Comment: In statement above you are passing $attachemt_id ito function as variable. That means that attachments id is there.

Comment: $video_m = get_post_meta( 'your url'); and then var_dump($video-m) - and find the tag

Comment: $video_m = get_post_meta( 'http://localhost/www/dev1/?p=51'); then var_dump($video_m); returns: bool(false)

Comment: I looked up that thema but i don't see anything like this in content.php. post_id = <?php the_ID(); ?> Where is that $attachement_id

Comment: there isn't, i need it!!

Comment: _“`$video_m = get_post_meta( 'localhost/www/dev1/?p=51');` then `var_dump($video_m);` returns: bool(false)”_ – that is not surprising, because `get_post_meta` wants the _post id_ as first parameter, and not a URL.

Comment: @CBroe yes,  i have seen that in wp reference.

Comment: The official documentation says it has to be the post id. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/ Whatever you read “elsewhere” might simply be wrong.